# Run Servlet Without POST or GET

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I am new to servlets, and would like to follow the Model2 paradigm by keeping all my "code" in servlets, and html/beans in jsp pages. But, is there a way to run a servlet when I access a jsp page without using a form submission. For example, I have a login page. If the user logs in and then somehow goes back to the login page I want to check for the existance of their session and automatically move them on to their welcome page. This is one real world example, but it seems it would come in handy to run code without having to submit a form for a multitude of reasons.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you dont have to submit a form to invoke a servlet.  All you have to do is have the browser hit the url that is mapped to the servlet.  That could happen when submitting a form, clicking a link, invoking an xhr, using curl or wget from the command line, etc.

Also, keeping *all* code in servlets is not good design.  Your servlets should handle incoming requests, invoke business logic implemented in separate classes (for good modularity and testing purposes), and return the appropriate response.

Comment: I thought the "mvc/model 2" was a design practise that focused around keeping ALL code out of the jsp page?

Comment: right, but that doesn't mean move *all* if it into the servlets.  It means to have a good MVC design on the server.

Comment: So when I link to the servlet directly, how can I load the jsp page containing the design aspects, but also keep the doPost() from firing (because in some cases the doPost required submitted form data?

Comment: you need to have a different servlet for each url.  See http://javapapers.com/servlet/what-is-servlet-mapping/

Answer (score 0):

If I recall correctly, in Model2, the user never navigates to (JSP) pages - only controllers (servlets). Trying to access a lower layer of code (a servlet) direcltly from a view (the page) is a violation of MVC/Model2.

Comment: What if I don't have much backend code to execute on a particular page and its really redundant to call a servlet? And how do I pass the user the jsp (design) without forwarding to the jsp page?

Comment: If your application is simple enough that Model2 is more of a burden than a benefit, don't use Model2. In Model2, you can either *forward* to the page with `RequestDispatcher#forward`, or *redirect* to another controller with `ServletResponse#sendRedirect`, and it might be permissible to redirect directly to a JSP that doesn't need to call *any* backend code.

Comment: In your example, there should be a login **servlet**, not a page. If the user *isn't* not logged in, *forward* to the JSP with the login form. If the user *is* logged in, you *redirect* to the welcome page / servlet. (That said, a filter based solution as described in another answer would likely be more flexible because it would allow you to intercept anonymous users trying to access secure pages.)